# Struts2 change fielderrors.flt

Tags: templates, struts2, freemarker

I have taken fielderror.flt from struts2 source and i want to make a freemarker macro to customize the display field errors  but when the macro is calling I am getting the following error :

> Expected hash. fieldErrors evaluated instead to freemarker.core.Macro on line 190, column 22 in
>   WEB-INF/templates/flt/admin/isis/macros.flt. The problematic
>
> ### instruction:
>
> ==> assignment: eKeys=fieldErrors.keySet() [on line 190, column 5 in WEB-INF/templates/flt/admin/isis/macros.flt]  in user-directive
>   fieldError_a [on line 6, column 17 in
>   WEB-INF/pages/admin/security/simpleUserGroup/edit/editSimpleUserGroupMainContent.flt]
>   in include "editSimpleUserGroupMainContent.flt" [on line 76, column 33
>   in
>
> ### WEB-INF/pages/admin/security/simpleUserGroup/edit/editSimpleUserGroupLayout.flt]
>
> Java backtrace for programmers:
>   ---------- freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash. fieldErrors evaluated instead to freemarker.core.Macro on line 190,
>   column 22 in WEB-INF/templates/flt/admin/isis/macros.flt.     at
>   freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:135)
>     at freemarker.core.Dot._getAsTemplateModel(Dot.java:78) .....

the code is from original struts2 flt templates. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you saying that the original template also uses `fieldErrors.keySet()`? Then what defines the `fieldErrors` macro in your case?

Comment: I dont know i did not find any comment

Answer (score 0):

One solution is mixing struts2 tag with freemarker like this

```
<#macro fieldErrorsTag>

<div id="system-message-container">
            <@s.if test="hasFieldErrors()">
        <div class="alert alert-error" id="system-message">
            <h4 class="alert-heading"></h4>
            <div>
                            <@s.iterator value="fieldErrors">
                                <p><@s.property escape="false" /></p>
                            </@s.iterator>
            </div>
        </div>
       </@s.if>
</div>
</#macro>
```

but i think mixing tags should be avoided